# Sign in to a 3rd party excel add-in from vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 3rd party ribbon (SNL Financial) add-in installed in Excel (2010 version) and I would like to have some vba code to automatically "sign-in" to the 3rd party ribbon.  I've tried simply "recording" a macro that clicks on the ribbon and then clicks on the "sign-in" button, but no code shows up in the VBA macro recorder.  Any ideas?

Comment: Macro recorder only records certain actions - it will not for example capture any interaction with your add-in.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Does anyone know how to include commands to sign in to 3rd party add ins?

Comment: That would depend on exactly how your add-in manages the sign-on process.  There's no one generic set of "sign on" steps, so you'd need to provide more-detailed info here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal "sign on macro" or method to login to all Excel Add-ins. Your best bet is to leverage something the developer has already built. Assuming you've already searched the web unsuccessfully, you can search your VBA **Objects Browser** which would be the most likely place to find any VBA options that a developer will allow you to use.

To do this, from the VBA editor screen click:

- **Tools** / **Reference**. Make sure whatever add-in you have is checked in this list. It might not be the exact name so you may need to do some research to find it. Click okay to return to the VBA editor.
- Click on **VIEW** / **Object Browser**. Hopefully you will see in the drop down menu that starts with `<ALL LIBRARIES>` the name of your add-in.
- In the object browser, with you add-in selected, you should have access to view all API/MACRO tools the add-in has already built. Some of them may be intended for your use, and some may not. You might get lucky and find one you can leverage or take the code and research more on google for a solution.

Bottomline, there is no direct answer to your problem, but the above instructions would be the best place to start looking for your custom solution. Good luck.

**Extra Bonus just for your particular SNL issue**
For technical support contact SNL Support, visit this page:
http://sc.snl.com/SNLDSWebService2/Download.aspx

Comment: Thanks to all for for helping.  I'll try the VBA objects brower idea.  Otherwise I guess I'll have to contact the add in developer.

Comment: Thanks @Jcarl. Sorry there isn't a "magic bullet" answer to your question. Would you mind validating my answer as correct? I realize this does provide a direct answer, but it is the proper response to your question. I also included some contact information for your particular SNL add-in. Best of luck.

Comment: @Jcarl Did you get your solution? If so can you pls share it. I'm also working on same problem ?